# use result of mysql query into a new query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql table.

```
name    |     total
chris   |     5
jan     |     3
bob     |     2
eric    |     4
```

chris and jan were selected using this code

```
$query =  " select * from table where name = '$given_name' "; 
// &given_name = result from another query
```

I want to store the result of the query to a variable.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $result = $row['name']; 
} // i want to store both chris and jan to $result
```

Then i will use the result of the query to another query. I want to select the remaining names. Not the ones on the first query. I want chris and jan not to be selected with this query because it is stored in $result

```
select * from table where name != $result ;
```

But one name was just stored in $result. I want them both to be stored in $result.

Comment: You seem to be showing the same query on the same table as if it's two different queries.  Long story short, you should probably just use a single query to do the whole thing.

Comment: That is just an example. I wll just get the idea on how i am able to store the result of the query to be used on another query.

Comment: `mysqlfetch_assoc()` if that's a typo, can you fix it? It's incorrect. It should read as `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` if you're using the mysqli_ api to connect with. If you're using mysql_, then that should read as `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Easiest way would (probably) be to bind and store the results. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

Comment: btw; why are you using such an old and deprecated api? It's also not available in any of the newer versions of php. You're best to switch now and to avoid having to potentially spend a lot of time to convert code. It's also not very safe to use also. @kristyanmarkes

Comment: im just using it locally

Comment: How do you know that you want to get chris and jan? Or do you simply want to get the first two names returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `FIND_IN_SET` to see if the names had been fetched before. Firstly you need to make `$result` an array of all the names:

```
$result = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $result[] = $row['name']; 
}
```

Then you can write your query to exclude the names in `$result`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(name, '" . implode(',', $result) . "')";
```

Comment: i tried to echo $ result with your code but it gives me an output "array"

Comment: Yes, `$result` does become an array. If you want to see what's in it, use `print_r($result)` instead.

Comment: thanks it displayed already but i want to display just the names. here's what it outputs Array ( [0] => bob )Array ( [0] => jan). how can i remove those special characters

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(name, '" . implode(',', $result) . "')" or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 $name = $row['name'];
 echo $name;
}

im having an error running the code ( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @kristyanmarkes Search google how to display values in array in PHP. You will get tons solutions.

Comment: Try this: `foreach ($result as $name) echo $name;`

Comment: The first code in my answer should be used on the result set from the query which gets 'chris' and 'jan' (in your example). Then you can generate the second query using those result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use database query like below to exclude `chris` and `jan`:

```
select * from table where name NOT IN( $result );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do not know the names of the resultset you can simply (a) select the first two names from the resultset, (b) concatenate them in a string and finally (c) use "NOT IN" as your query parameter.

```
$numPicks = 2; // decide how many names you want in the list
// OR if you want to exclude ALL names found in the first query
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

$nameList = ''; // start with an empty string
for($i=0; $i<$numPicks; $i++) { // then use $num_rows here instead of numPicks
    $nameList .= $row['name'].',';
}
$nameList = rtrim($nameList,','); // remove trailing comma from the string

$sql = "select * from table where name NOT IN ($nameList)";
```